# JavaScript parseInt IE Nan error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, parseint

I have function in JavaScript:

```
function calc(num) {
    if (num <= 22) {
            return parseInt(num);
    } else {
            num += '';
            var curr = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < num['length']; i++) {
                    curr += parseInt(num[i]);
            };
            return curr;
    };
};
```

This function calculates new number like:
if I have number greater than 22, this function returns new number which is a sum of it's subdigits (e.g. 28 > 22 => return (2+8) ).

This function works great in Firefox, but I'm getting "NaN" error in Internet Explorer with numbers greater than 22. So the problem must be in "else".

What's wrong?

Comment: Please supply a decimal radix to `parseInt()`: `parseInt(num[i], 10)`.  It's a very bad habit to omit that second parameter.

Comment: A guess: Try `num = num + '';` if `+=` is not defined for string concatenation.

Comment: I've tried radix, but no effect

Comment: Try `num.charAt(i)` instead of `num[i]`. I think IE does not implement array access for strings.

Comment: @ieaglle - even if radix isn't the solution to this problem, you should still include it; as Michael says, it is bad practice to omit it, and it will come back to bite you one day.

Comment: charAt works, but I don't know whose answer was first Felix' or Alex' :)

Comment: @Spudley got it, I've included radix' in all my parseInts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to `num.charAt(i)` as you cannot access string characters with `String[offset]` in IE.

(`s = "qwe"; alert(typeof s[1] === 'undefined')` is `true`)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function calc(num) {
    if (num <= 22) {
            return parseInt(num);
    } else {
            number = num.toString();
            var curr = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {

                    curr += parseInt(number.charAt(i));
            };
            return curr;
    };
};


alert(calc(23));
```

worked for me on firefox and IE

Comment: Don't forget the radix as others have commented else based numbers like "0123" will not give what you expect